# Magento paypal payments standard method not showing credit memo button on invoice page

Tags: php, magento, paypal, web, payment-gateway

I am using paypal payment standard methotd for payment.
everything works fine.

payment action is : Sale

and IPN also working properly

but unfortunately i am not able to refund online.

Credit memo button is showing on order detail page but not showing on invoice details page.
as i know i can only refund online option from invoice details credit memo button.

have anything changed from paypal ?

Thanks in advance
Simranjeet singh

Comment: Did you capture your payment? What is the invoice status? 
It should be ‘Paid’. If it’s paid and captured within paypal you should be able to refund online

Comment: yes invoice status is paid

captured payment immediately because payment action is "Sale"

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem.  I am having the same problem.

Comment: i'm having the same problem too

Comment: i have the same issue